# Upload a file using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am ussing react js to create a uploader for different files(EX: pdf);

```js
class MyUpload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileList: [
      {
        uid: "-1",
        name: "xxx.png",
        status: "done",
        url:
          "https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = (info) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];

    // 1. Limit the number of uploaded files
    // Only to show two recent uploaded files, and old ones will be replaced by the new
    fileList = fileList.slice(-2);

    // 2. Read from response and show file link
    fileList = fileList.map((file) => {
      console.log(file);
      if (file.response) {
        // Component will show file.url as link
        file.url = file.response.url;
      }
      return file;
    });

    this.setState({ fileList });
  };

  render() {
    const props = {
      action:
        "https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg",
      onChange: this.handleChange,
      multiple: true,
      showUploadList: {
        showDownloadIcon: true,
        downloadIcon: "download ",
        showRemoveIcon: true,
        removeIcon: (
          <StarOutlined
            onClick={(e) => console.log(e, "custom removeIcon event")}
          />
        )
      }
    };
    return (
      <Upload {...props} fileList={this.state.fileList}>
        <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button>
      </Upload>
    );
  }
}
```

When i upload a pdf file i get `upload error`, plus i can't download the pdf. 
Question: How to make pdf uploadable and also to have the possibility to download the item?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-control-over-file-list-antd4100-forked-26osw?file=/index.js:218-1688

Answer (score 0):

there are tons of the third part packages for uploading files and customize which type of file should be accepted. **react-dropzone** is a great package that is giving a lot of control.

Here is link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone

Here are some use cases:

```js
import React, {useCallback} from 'react'
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'
 
function MyDropzone() {
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // here you get array of the file
  }, [])
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({
  onDrop
 accept: ".pdf",
  })
 
  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ?
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p> :
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: do you know a solution for Ant Design  uploader?

Comment: @Shreyans Shrivastav, do you know a solution?

Comment: @Itamar, could you help?